# How to cancel async task android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have made custom video player in which i am starting video in async task and it works perfect but when i lock the screen, video is running inspite of this. Please recommend any good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
       super.onDestroy();
       asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create the class object of your Asynch task class

in your activity like below example

```
customAsynchTask   mytask   = new    customAsynchTask();
```

and then you can stop the execution of the method as per your requirement

```
mytask.cancel(true);
```

like in your case you can use the .cancel on onpause of your activity .